# How can I encode a rule tree of multiple depths in Dhall?

Tags: directed-acyclic-graphs, dhall

I'm trying to move some error prone YAML into Dhall to make some system configuration simpler. I have a tree that looks like:

```yaml
composite:
  condition: And
  rules:
    - composite:
        condition: And
        rules:
          - leaf:
              static: true
          - leaf:
              exists: some-property-to-lookup
    - composite:
        condition: Or
        rules:
          - composite:
              condition: And
              rules:
                - leaf:
                    static: true
                - leaf:
                    exists: some-property-to-lookup
```

I'm trying to encode this in Dhall and I can't seem to provide the compiler the right information. My latest try looks like:

```
let Field
    : Type
    = < B : { static : Bool } | S : { exists : Text } >

let Condition
    : Type
    = < And | Or | Not >

let Node
    : Type
    = ∀(Node : Type) →
      ∀(Leaf : { leaf : Field }) →
      ∀(Branch : { composite : { condition : Condition, rules : List Node } }) →
        Node

let example
    : Node
    = ∀(Node : Type) →
      ∀(Leaf : { leaf : Field }) →
      ∀(Branch : { composite : { condition : Condition, rules : List Node } }) →
        Branch
          { composite =
            { condition = Condition.And
            , rules =
              [ Branch
                  { composite =
                    { condition = Condition.And
                    , rules = [ Leaf { leaf = Field.S { exists = "hi" } } ]
                    }
                  }
              , Branch
                  { composite =
                    { condition = Condition.Or
                    , rules = [ Leaf { leaf = Field.S { static = true } } ]
                    }
                  }
              , Branch
                  { composite =
                    { condition = Condition.And
                    , rules =
                      [ Branch
                          { composite =
                            { condition = Condition.And
                            , rules =
                              [ Leaf { leaf = Field.S { exists = "hi" } } ]
                            }
                          }
                      , Branch
                          { composite =
                            { condition = Condition.Or
                            , rules =
                              [ Leaf { leaf = Field.S { static = true } } ]
                            }
                          }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
              ]
            }
          }

in  example
```

But I get `Error: Not a function`. Any pointers would be appreciated.

I also tried w/ the Graph module, but I can't seem to convert that to YAML directly.

Comment: You are trying to call `Branch` as if it were a function, but it's just a type (in particular, a record type).

Comment: Couple of other typos: you use `Field.S` instead of `Field.B when creating a boolean field, and `true` should be `True`.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to simplify and missed that. So, the gist is that the constructor needs to be implemented manually for recursive types? I saw https://github.com/Gabriel439/graph but I couldn't get it to serialize; it feels like I'm missing some concept here.

Comment: I juuuust barely grasp the concept myself, and I don't think I could provide a good answer. Gabriel is around here, and will probably answer this question himself, but in the mean time you might want to read `https://docs.dhall-lang.org/howtos/How-to-translate-recursive-code-to-Dhall.html`

Comment: Thanks, I stared at that for a good while :-). Taking a look at https://github.com/Gabriel439/graph/blob/master/package.dhall#L40 I think I might not be able to do what I need; I'm looking to have teammates create a config for a rule set while hiding the details in a separate library, but it looks like all the vertices are declared ahead of time. (Maybe I'm looking for a new feature, but I've seen some solutions I thought were improbable in Dhall before.)

Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
let Field
    : Type
    = < B : { static : Bool } | S : { exists : Text } >

let Condition
    : Type
    = < And | Or | Not >

let Node
    : Type
    = ∀(Node : Type) →
      ∀(Leaf : { leaf : Field } → Node) →
      ∀(Branch : { composite : { condition : Condition, rules : List Node } } → Node) →
        Node

let example
    : Node
    = λ(Node : Type) →
      λ(Leaf : { leaf : Field } → Node) →
      λ(Branch : { composite : { condition : Condition, rules : List Node } } → Node) →
        Branch
          { composite =
            { condition = Condition.And
            , rules =
              [ Branch
                  { composite =
                    { condition = Condition.And
                    , rules = [ Leaf { leaf = Field.S { exists = "hi" } } ]
                    }
                  }
              , Branch
                  { composite =
                    { condition = Condition.Or
                    , rules = [ Leaf { leaf = Field.B { static = True } } ]
                    }
                  }
              , Branch
                  { composite =
                    { condition = Condition.And
                    , rules =
                      [ Branch
                          { composite =
                            { condition = Condition.And
                            , rules =
                              [ Leaf { leaf = Field.S { exists = "hi" } } ]
                            }
                          }
                      , Branch
                          { composite =
                            { condition = Condition.Or
                            , rules =
                              [ Leaf { leaf = Field.B { static = True } } ]
                            }
                          }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
              ]
            }
          }

in  example
```

Here is the `diff` between the two:

```
12,13c12,13
<       ∀(Leaf : { leaf : Field }) →
<       ∀(Branch : { composite : { condition : Condition, rules : List Node } }) →
---
>       ∀(Leaf : { leaf : Field } → Node) →
>       ∀(Branch : { composite : { condition : Condition, rules : List Node } } → Node) →
18,20c18,20
<     = ∀(Node : Type) →
<       ∀(Leaf : { leaf : Field }) →
<       ∀(Branch : { composite : { condition : Condition, rules : List Node } }) →
---
>     = λ(Node : Type) →
>       λ(Leaf : { leaf : Field } → Node) →
>       λ(Branch : { composite : { condition : Condition, rules : List Node } } → Node) →
34c34
<                     , rules = [ Leaf { leaf = Field.S { static = true } } ]
---
>                     , rules = [ Leaf { leaf = Field.B { static = True } } ]
52c52
<                               [ Leaf { leaf = Field.S { static = true } } ]
---
>                               [ Leaf { leaf = Field.B { static = True } } ]
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Really enjoying using Dhall so far. Really appreciate the help!!